# Issue with Internet Explorer and Cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies

I´m having an issue with Internet Explorer and cookies.

Here´s a little bit of background on the problem:

After authenticating on a web site (https://auth.corp.bla.com), this sets a cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: XXXX=YYYYYY;Domain=.corp.bla.com;Path=/;httpOnly
```

On a different web site (e.g. http://anysite.com), we request a JS from the site where we authenticated before (e.g. https://auth.corp.bla.com/auth/users/file.js) but this request does not contain the cookie XXXX that was set before. We need this cookie in this request because the content of the returned JS file depends on this.

Additional remarks:

- The p3p header is present in the response that sets the cookie (CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"), however, there is no privacy policy file in the server.
- I don´t see any report on IE saying that cookies have been restricted
  or blocked for https://auth.corp.bla.com
- This is working correctly in other browsers (Chrome & FF).
- If I make a request by pasting the url of the JS file directly in the browser
  I get the correct result and the request includes the cookie in the
  header.
- I´m using IE 10, but the same problem exists with previous versions
  of IE (9 and 8).
- There´s no iframe anywhere.
- None of the domains contain an underscore.